# ¿Cómo puedo usar una variable como RegEx en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

¿Cómo puedo usar una variable para crear una RegEx?

Esto intenté hasta ahora:

```js
var variable = prompt("nombre");
var regex = \variable/g\;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si tu quieres usar una variable como regex, tienes que construir un objeto regex así:

```
var patron = "regex";
var reg = new RegExp(patron,"g");

"El zorro marón salta".replace(reg,"cambiado");
```

Ten cuidado con el hecho que hay que escapar la expresión regular.

[Documentación de RegExp en español](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)

Comment: para que sea la palabra exacta? ej: zorro y no asdfzorroas o asssdzorro

Comment: Es un ejemplo no más, no usé ningun regex en concreto, hay que remplazar "regex" con lo que quieres buscar, por ejemplo "\\w+" para palabras enteras.